# Should we need to repeat on the pronoun after "because"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Should we need to repeat on the pronoun after the word "because"?

For example:

> "This bone is also called the “tail” because **(it is / is)** in the end of the
>   body"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the pronoun needs to be repeated because it is part of a clause, which means that there needs to be a subject. The pronoun would only be omitted if it were part of a compound verb in one clause, such as "The bone is also called the 'tail' and is in the end of the body."